# Is there any possible way to make this python for loop more simple?

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, dictionary, range

I am quite new to programming and I am learning python by using Python Crash Course. I was wondering if there any way to make the print statements more simple and shorter?

```py
father = {'age': 26, 'skin': 'dark', 'complexity': 'tall'}  

mother = {'age': 30, 'skin': 'white', 'complexity': 'small'}

sister = {'age': 15, 'skin': 'white', 'complexity': 'tall'}

people = [father, mother, sister]  # stored 3  dictionaries inside a list

for character in range(1): # loop the list in range function, loop once 

   print(f"\nMy fathers age is: {father['age']}, skin is: {father['skin']}, complexity: {father['complexity']}")
   print("")
   print(f"\nMy mothers age is: {mother['age']}, skin is: {mother['skin']}, complexity: {mother['complexity']}")
   print("")
   print(f"\nMy sisters age is: {sister['age']}, skin is: {sister['skin']}, complexity: {sister['complexity']}")
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need a loop if it iterates only once?

Comment: Yes, well it is just an exercise from python crash course, thanks for the comment

Comment: Are you allowed to change `people` to `dict` type? Or it should be a list?

Comment: In the exercise he asks to store the dictionaries in a list called people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to change the type of `people` to `dict`, then you can do like this:

```py
father = {'age': 26, 'skin': 'dark',  'complexity': 'tall'}
mother = {'age': 30, 'skin': 'white', 'complexity': 'small'}
sister = {'age': 15, 'skin': 'white', 'complexity': 'tall'}

people = {
    "father": father,
    "mother": mother,
    "sister": sister
}

for name in people:
    data = ", ".join([f"{k} is: {v}" for k, v in people[name].items()])
    print(f"My {name}'s", data)
```

What we are doing here is, iterating the dictionary `people` (by its keys as `name`), inside the `for loop` we are iterating the sub-dictionaries (father, mother, sister) and making string by their key-value pairs using `inline for loop`, and at the end joining them with `", "` and assigning the resulting string to variable `data`. Then, printing people's name and their data

If you are not allowed to change the type of `people`, then you can do like this:

```py
people = [father, mother, sister]
names = ["father", "mother", "sister"]

for i in range(len(people)):
    data = ", ".join([f"{k} is: {v}" for k, v in people[i].items()])
    print(f"My {names[i]}'s", data)
```

There we are simply iterating by list index

The output will be the same:

```
My father's age is: 26, skin is: dark, complexity is: tall
My mother's age is: 30, skin is: white, complexity is: small
My sister's age is: 15, skin is: white, complexity is: tall
```